# HTML element doesn't get focus when clicked

Tags: html, css, frontend

[image: list-item]

I need the elements to get focus on click, which will trigger special css for them swapping their bg-color and color (ex. first element).
**I achieved the current result by manually giving :focus to the element from chrome dev-tools.**

```css
.btns>span:focus {
  color: #2DB46A;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.btns>span {
  padding: 12px 0 8px 20px;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.btns {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #2DB46A;
  font-family: Facile;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list-container">
  <li class="btns"><span>pcb design</span></li>
  <li class="btns"><span>analog design</span></li>
  <li class="btns"><span>power design</span></li>
  <li class="btns"><span>wireless design</span></li>
  <li class="btns"><span>fpga design</span></li>
  <li class="btns"><span>embedded software</span></li>
</ul>
```

**How to get the result like the first element on clicking for every one of the elements.**

Comment: This is jsx, thank you for noticing, will fix now :)

Comment: create a code snippet pls

Comment: Sorry, not sure about what you mean

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please note [Html DOM level 2](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html) specifications:

Element won't actually take focus unless it's one of the following:

- HTMLAnchorElement/HTMLAreaElement with an href
- HTMLInputElement/HTMLSelectElement/HTMLTextAreaElement/HTMLButtonElement but not with `disabled` (IE actually gives you an error if you try), and file uploads have unusual behaviour for security reasons
- HTMLIFrameElement (though focusing it doesn't do anything useful). Other embedding elements also, maybe, I haven't tested them all.
- Any element with a `tabindex`

So if you want your `.btns>span:focus` to actually take focus, you will have to assign `tabindex` to your element.

---

**Edited for addition:**

An example by *Weston Ruter* can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/westonruter/UAWRc/)

Comment: I tried the variant with the <a href="#"> tag, but because I'm using react, a "#" is added to the url and the components rerender each time the anchor is pressed and in result I'm getting x(clickTimes) amount of the components. After it decided to use span.

Comment: Used the "Weston Ruter option" with tabIndex="0", worked, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on [Barr J's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53029635/4375327). As he said, use `tabindex` and `:focus` selector. So I think you should mark his answer as accepted.

Also, but maybe you did it on purpose, keep styling the sub-element `span` and not the `li` one, otherwise the focus border (dotted grey) will cover the orange one (Firefox at least) and you'll end up getting an ugly rendering.

```
.btns:focus > span {
  color: #2DB46A;
  background-color: #fff;
  border:1px solid orange;
}
```

By the way you should size the `span` element according to its border box, other wise it will be bigger than the `ul` element because of its padding value:

```
.btns>span {
  padding: 12px 0 8px 20px;
  box-sizing:border-box; /* Here */
}
```

Below a working snippet.

```css
.btns {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: Facile;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: #2DB46A;
  color: #fff;
}

.btns>span {
  padding: 12px 0 8px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.btns:focus>span {
  color: #2DB46A;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list-container">
  <li class="btns" tabindex="0"><span>pcb design</span></li>
  <li class="btns" tabindex="1"><span>analog design</span></li>
  <li class="btns" tabindex="2"><span>power design</span></li>
  <li class="btns" tabindex="3"><span>wireless design</span></li>
  <li class="btns" tabindex="4"><span>fpga design</span></li>
  <li class="btns" tabindex="5"><span>embedded software</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The :active selector affects ONLY the elements that are clicked and not unclicked yet. Time between mousebtndown and mousebtnup. I need the element to change colors when clicked, e.g. focused, like being focused with tab.